# I'm losing data when my Raspberry pi talks to its USB connected Arduino

Tags: arduino, usb, raspberry-pi, serial

Some very simple code, which I got somewhere on the Internet
Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.print("You sent me: ");
    Serial.println(data);
  }
}
```

Raspberry Pi code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.write(b"Hello 1 from Raspberry Pi!\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(line)
    time.sleep(1)

    ser.write(b"Hello 2 from Raspberry Pi!\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(line)
    time.sleep(1)

    ser.write(b"Hello 3 from Raspberry Pi!\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(line)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So the plan is to send some data from the Pi to the Arduino and get it echoed back, but always the first line is missing. I appear to see just a blank line coming back ie a line feed.

The output:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ./fine.py

You sent me: Hello 2 from Raspberry Pi!
You sent me: Hello 3 from Raspberry Pi!
```

So where is the first line disappearing to?

George

Comment: What happens if you prefix the first message with a \n?

Comment: Makes no difference !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are losing the first line to the bootloader delay of the Arduino, after opening the port triggers a reset via the traditional wiring of the modem control lines to the ATmega reset, and the traditional default manipulation of those on serial device open.

Generally speaking you want to avoid using time delays to make serial code work, but in this case you could reasonably put a few seconds delay between the open and the first query.

Also beware of debug messages generating responses which are longer than the input - it's entirely possible for this to result in saturating the output baud rate, even when the input stays well within its capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Awsome, I inserted a 2 second delay:

```
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
    time.sleep(2)
    ser.write(b"Hello 1 from Raspberry Pi!\n")
```

and now I am seeing the expected output !!
You sent me: Hello 1 from Raspberry Pi!
You sent me: Hello 2 from Raspberry Pi!
You sent me: Hello 3 from Raspberry Pi!
Thanks!!!!